# Scaling Django using cache and database clusters

Tags: python, django, database, caching, memcached

I'm working on the optimization and the scalability of a django project. 
At the moment, our infrastructure is as follow :

- One web server;
- One database server (Postgresql);
- Media and Static files are managed using aws S3.

We want to scale our infrastructure according to this figure : 
[image]

I read the django documentation about the database replication, and the django caching built in API. But things are not clear for me in case we have multiple web app servers. Should we mention the same databases locations in the settings.py files so that all the web app servers use the same cache servers and database cluster ? 
Any documentation that explains in details the implementation of this architecture ?

Comment: The topic of your question is several levels above actual programming and therefore off-topic on SO.